# How would we know that a parameter can be passed into the interface's constructor?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

When I create a `priceFeed` object of type `AggregatorV3Interface`, I use code that looks like this (from all the documentation):

```js
AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);
```

But I look into the code of Chainlink's [AggregatorV3Interface.sol](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol)

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
interface AggregatorV3Interface {   

      function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
    
      function description() external view returns (string memory);
    
      function version() external view returns (uint256);
    
      function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
        external
        view
        returns (
          uint80 roundId,
          int256 answer,
          uint256 startedAt,
          uint256 updatedAt,
          uint80 answeredInRound
        );
    
      function latestRoundData()
        external
        view
        returns (
          uint80 roundId,
          int256 answer,
          uint256 startedAt,
          uint256 updatedAt,
          uint80 answeredInRound
        ); }
```

I don't see / understand where in the definition of the code that it can accept a contract address.

```
AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);
```

I'm passing `0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e` to this object, yet I don't see a constructor that accepts an address.

Where can we verify/check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interface is just a list of contract functions you can call, and doesn't have any logic itself. In our solidity, when we combine an address with an interface, we get an object that we can call functions on.

Let's say we have a contract at address `0x000...01` that has some function `readMe()`, and we want to call that function in our own contract. How can we do that?

We couldn't simply do:

```js
0x000...01.readMe()
```

Since `0x000...01` is an `address` type, and it doesn't have the `readMe()` function. But what we can do, is assign an interface that has the `readMe()` function to that address:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT 
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
    
interface IReading {  
  function readMe() external view returns (uint256);
}

contract MyContract {
  IReading readableContract = IReading(0x000...01);
  uint256 readValue = readableContract.readMe();
}
```

Interfaces are special in that they can't have a constructor, but you can always put an address inside their instantiation arguments to get an object that has the functions you'd expect.

So for Chainlink, it's the same thing:

```js
AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e);
priceFeed.latestRoundData()
```

Since we want to call the `latestRoundData` function.

Let me know if that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! Yes, it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an `interface`, interfaces cannot have constructor definitions or state variables. So you need to know in advance how to use it. When you implement it in a contract, then you create a constructor for that contract that receives that aggregator contract address, or some other logic to have it or change it dynamically.

For example, here you can see a list of aggregators: https://data.chain.link/

Here I chose the ETH/USD aggregator: https://data.chain.link/ethereum/mainnet/crypto-usd/eth-usd

And here I can see its implementation: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4ec3df9cbd43714fe2740f5e3616155c5b8419#code

Look at the `AggregatorProxy` that implements the `AggregatorV3Interfaces`:

```js
contract AggregatorProxy is AggregatorV2V3Interface, Owned {...}
```

And it has a constructor to accept the aggregator contract address since it acts as a proxy.

Ir your example, the 0xD4a33860578De61DBAbDc8BFdb98FD742fA7028e aggregator address is an actual implementation of the interfaces and your contract simply calls it like any other contract. The interface is just so you know how to use the contract that implemented it. Instead of you having a copy of the whole contract implementation to be able to use a reference to it, you just use its interface, then cast the address of the implementation contract like `Interface interface = Interfaces(implementationContractAddress);` and use it.
The EVM will then call the actual implementation contract accordingly.